# React can't recognize firebase/auth or @firebase/auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue that I can't figure out the solution, I built this page a while ago, and now I need to add an authentication section, I already had the firebase installed because of the deployment, so I as I wrote the code most of the methods wouldn't be recognized or appear. I tried to look for solutions, used `firebase/compat/auth`

but nothing. This is the code I have

the Firebase config file:

```
 import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxx",
        authDomain: "xxx",
        projectId: "xxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxx",
        appId: "xxx",
        measurementId: "xxxx"
      };;
      
    const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    const db=firebase.firestore();
    
    const auth = firebase.auth(firebaseApp);
    
    
    export { auth }
    
    
    export default db;


The implementation

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {auth} from '../../firebase.config.js'
import {onAuthStateChanged,signInWithEmailAndPassword,signOut} from "firebase/auth"


function AppAuthentication(){

    const [loginEmail,setLoginEmail] = useState("");
    const [loginEmailPass, setLoginEmailPass] = useState("");

    const [user,setUser] = useState({});


    const login = async () => {
        try{
            const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,loginEmail,loginEmailPass);
        console.log(user)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }

    }

    const logout = async () => {
        await signOut(auth)
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div>
            <h3> Login</h3>
            <br></br>
            <input placeholder='Your email'
                onChange={(event)=>{
                    setLoginEmail(event.target.value);
                }}
            />
            <br></br>
            <input placeholder='Your Password'
                onChange={(event)=>{
                    setLoginEmailPass(event.target.value)
                }}
            />
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={login}>Login</button>

            <br></br>
            <h4>User:</h4>

            <br></br>
            <button onClick={logout}>Sign Out</button>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AppAuthentication;
```

The Error message I get is:

```
Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'onAuthStateChanged'.
Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'signOut'.
```

This is the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.20.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.19",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "firebase": "^8.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.9.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy:firebase": "npm run build && firebase deploy"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for thee help. my Firebase version in 8.10.1

Comment: Are you sure you have the right version of firebase installed? The older version did not have those members and from what i can see you are using the syntax of an older version for firestore and auth initialization

Comment: There is no Firebase `10.9.2`. The latest version is `9.10.0`. Please share your `package.json` file as well.